# Gradle multi project build.gradle traversal dependencies

Tags: gradle

I have a rather large `build.gradle` file where I have 28 Gradle projects. I am having some issues with traversal dependencies. For example i have to projects `Harbor.Client` and `Harbor.Models`. My Client has a dependency on my model project. However, the project where I use the client also needs to define a dependency on the model's project, instead of just getting it from the client project.

Example

```
project(':Harbor.Client') {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':Harbor.Models')
    }
}
project(':Harbor.Models') {
    dependencies {
    }
}
project(':Application') {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':Harbor.Client')
        implementation project(':Harbor.Models')
    }
}
```

Is there a setting I can set, so that the `Application` project does not need to set a direct dependency on `Harbor.Models`?

```
project(':Harbor.Client') {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':Harbor.Models')
    }
}
project(':Harbor.Models') {
    dependencies {
    }
}
project(':Application') {
    dependencies {
        // Gets ':Harbor.Models' though ':Harbor.Client'
        implementation project(':Harbor.Client')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer was to use the API dependency instead of implementation

```
project(':Harbor.Client') {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'

    dependencies {
        implementation project(':Harbor.Models')
    }
}
project(':Harbor.Models') {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'

    dependencies {
    }
}
project(':Application') {
    dependencies {
        // Gets ':Harbor.Models' though ':Harbor.Client'
        api project(':Harbor.Client')
    }
}
```